# How does a router find it's default gateway?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet, arp

I understand Address Resolution Protocol and how it broadcasts to  all devices on the subnet to find the MAC address of the destination. I know when a computer is unable to find the destination through ARP then it concludes it must be on another subnet so it sends it up to the router.

If the destination is indeed half way across the globe and the router has to hop to your ISPs router, how does the router find the IP address of it's default gateway in the first place?

Comment: I think it has to do with the ISP you are using, which are different for large companies which rent different IP's: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_gateway

Comment: **Short Answer:** Per it's configurations...

Comment: There are protocols.  For instance, DHCP/IPv4.  Many routers use that to get information from an Internet Service Provider.  Many, many, many, many other routers are just manually configured with such "static IP address" details.  Those are the answers for IPv4, which seems to be what you're interested in, since you mention ARP.  For IPv6, the most official protocol may be one using  "router advertisements".

Comment: I do see in my routers routing table that it contains a default route called 0.0.0.0

Comment: @user4191887 out of interest, what model of router is it and how did you view its routing table?  Also,i'm not sure but i'd guess that perhaps it makes no difference if the destination is halfway across the globe. perhaps it'd be the same default gateway. as the 'next hop' the next router on the journey, would be the same

Comment: "*I know when a computer is unable to find the destination through ARP then it concludes it must be on another subnet so it sends it up to the router.*" This may be a misunderstanding if you think it tries ARP first.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @user4191887 A router wouldn't even attempt to use ARP unless it already knew the machine was on the same subnet. So how could it later conclude the machine was on another subnet? A router can't even try to use ARP unless it already knows the machine is on the same subnet -- it needs an IP address inside the subnet to put in the ARP request.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Okay, perhaps I worded it wrong. Do you mean to say that the origin computer checks the destination IP address against its own assigned subnet?

Comment: @user4191887 It checks the IP address against its routing table. If the next hop is over a network that uses ARP, then it uses ARP to locate the MAC address of the next hop. But if it's not on the local network, most likely it already knows the MAC address of the next hop, because that will be the router it's been using all along since it got its IP address from it by DHCP. In other words, that's backwards -- if it's not on the local network it doesn't have to use ARP at all, since ARP is a local network thing. It just sends it to its default gateway, whose MAC address it already knows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first paragraph isn't correct, it is the other way around.

ARP is used when the destination is known to be on the current network.  The sequence goes something like this:

#### Check routing table for destination

The routing table is tested in order of specificity, so while entries 192.0.0.0/8 and 192.168.0.0/16 both match 192.168.1.1, the second one is a more specific match.  0.0.0.0/0 matches everything, and is the default route.

#### Connected or routed?

The matched route will either be a connected network (the sending device has an IP address on the same network) or not.  If connected, then an arp is issued and the mac address retrieved (assuming the device exists) then the packet is handed off to layer 2 (ethernet) to transmit.

If the network is not a connected network, then it will have a gateway IP address.  That IP address *must* be on a connected network.  So again, an arp is issued for the gateway IP address the mac address retrieved, and the packet is handed off to layer 2 to transmit to the gateway IP.

#### At the next hop

Once it gets there, the exact same process is followed.  Either gateway has the destination IP address on a connected interface or it passes it off to another router.

#### Creating a routing table

There a many ways in which a routing table get populated.  The routes for connected networks are always configured by the OS based on the interface addresses.  In an environment where DHCP is used, an IP address is issued to an interface, and with it usually comes a default gateway.  So once DHCP is done, the device has a connected network route and a default route.

A more basic setup is static.  The device has a statically assigned IP address in its configuration, and a default gateway, and perhaps some static routes.  These are all manually configured on the device itself.

#### Dynamic routing

Clearly, when dealing with something as complex as the internet, manually adding static routes would be a difficult proposition.  It still happens at some levels, but everything is helped by dynamic routing protocols.  This is effectively where a router "owns" a set of IP address ranges, and communicates this to other routers.  All the routers learn routing from each other.

What this means is that an ISP can obtain a new IP range, and add it to its configuration, and advertise it out of its network, and the rest of the internet learns it without further configuration required.

#### Disclaimer

Please note that this entire description is a slimmed down version of what happens, there are many exceptions, caveats and different technologies that can alter the way the process unfolds, but this is how it works at the basic level.

Comment: you should quote what you call his "first premise" to which you refer. He wrote  "I understand Address Resolution Protocol and how it broadcasts to all devices on the subnet to find the MAC address of the destination"    It's not really a premise since it doesn't form the basis of what he says next. . i.e. what he says next is not dependent on that. And also, the first half of that is correct. The only thing that needs changing is where he wrote "find the MAC address of the destination"  it should be changed to something like "find the MAC address of the next device to send the packet to"

Comment: and the next device to send the packet to is  often potentially one of many, iimmediate destinations.  So to say MAC address of the destination might not be or isn't even,  wrong in that sense.

Comment: The first premise is the full statement, not the first sentence. I have changed it to "paragraph" for clarity.  Feel free to edit answers if you think they can be made clearer.

Comment: @Paul So I am right in saying that the origin PC first checks the DHCP'd subnet mask to see if the destination IP Address is in the same subnet?

Comment: @user4191887 Yes, this is effectively what happens - but really it is more that once dhcp happens a route is added to the routing table for the connected network.  In the course of processing any packet, the routing table is consulted. If it happens to be going to a local network, it will match the route added during dhcp and so be broadcast rather than routed.

Comment: @Paul Well this is the routing table for my local machine at this very moment https://i.imgur.com/6VjuhNH.png

Comment: @Paul Is ARP even used when communicating to other routers on the public internet? Like if I wanted to see google.com, my computer sees that it is on another subnet and thus does not need ARP, sending the HTTPS request to the default gateway by its MAC address to have it strip the Layer 2 frame and send the IP packet up to its default gateway, and so on?

Comment: ARP is used whenever a packet need to be sent to another device on the same network, it is the transition protocol between IP and ethernet.  So your machine will see google is not on the local network and yes will send it to the routers MAC address, but it must arp for the mac address of the router to send it there (ignoring arp caching). Then yes, the layer 2 stuff gets discarded and recreated for the next hop.

Comment: @user4191887  ARP or the ARP table is always used.. but the MAC address that it gets is always local, your subnet.  If your a computer X, sends a packet and the packet's  destination IP is outside of X's subnet, then X will look for its default gateway's MAC address, the MAC address of the local router's local interface, (gateway=router), and it will use that.  If the destination IP is on its own subnet or one of its own subnets, then it will look for the MAC address of that computer/device.

Answer (score 4):

This is where DHCP Servers come in. It will send a discovery request on the network using the ip 255.255.255.255 and the source ip being 0.0.0.0 since it doesn't know its own ip yet.

However this is where MAC Addresses come into play as well as the Discover packet is encapsulated into a Data Link Layer Ethernet frame to the target MAC Address of FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF and the source being whatever the network interface MAC address is.

The first Switch that recieves the packet for FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF will forward that discover packet on out of every single switch port except the one it came from since it doesn't know who FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF is either until the DHCP server sees it. If the DHCP servers is the first switch it won't forward the request as the switch is the DHCP server, it will recieve this frame and then it will send back information to the IP 255.255.255.255 since it doesn't know who is contacting them as the source ip is 0.0.0.0 but it does know the mac address that contacted them so it will encapsulate the offer packet with source mac being the dhcp server and the destination mac being whatever the device that sent the discover packet and its sent as a unicast and not as a broadcast.

The device then recieves this offer, than requests to lease, DHCP server than acknowledges the lease

Also note that if the default gateway means your communication has to go through other devices it usually means the route is statically set or in other words manually put in place as opposed to being a dynamic route as certain setups would make it impossible for a device to know which device is actually the default gateway.

Comment: I see both my public IP address and default gateway are of different subnets, what does this mean?

Comment: It means your modem gets its IP address information from the network your public IP address is on. Meaning there is another DHCP server, beyond your Modem and more likely as well another router or switch.

Answer (score 1):

The majority of internet connections use a form of PPP - be that PPPoA for DSL or PPPoE for cable.

PPP is a point-to-point protocol (which is its name after all) and as such the default gateway will always be whatever is at the other end of the PPP connection.

There is no need for this to be detected in any way, since it is what it is. The only question is whether to actively use the remote end of the PPP connection as your default gateway, which normally you would.